# How much of the C++ standard library requires compiler support?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards

Most of the standard library seems reasonably simple to implement either in terms of other parts of the library, in terms of OS sys-calls, or bare C++ code. A few more bits (e.g. `<atomic>`) probably require ASM implementations

But at least a few bits seem like they could only be implemented in terms of compiler intrinsics (e.g. `<source_location>` for sure, `std::has_virtual_destructor`, a few other parts of `<type_traits>`, etc).

This last group is of interest specifically because it sort of blurs the line between the standard *library* and the *language* standard itself. This is likely one of the most important limits on the portability of library implementations between compilers.

Specifically, my questions is:

> Is there a definitive list of the parts that fall into that last category? Is there a specific term the standard uses when talking about those things?

---

**Edit:**

As a bit of context, this question came up during a thought experiment about what a "bootstrap" compiler & library stack would look like. That is a ball of platform agnostic source code that, with an absolute minimum of manual steps and external dependencies, will get you to a fully standards conforming library and compiler. The focus would *not* be on performance, but on robustness, simplicity and a minimum kernel of ["trust it to actually be correct"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Erdriley/487/papers/Thompson_1984_ReflectionsonTrustingTrust.pdf) external dependencies.

As such, the way things are generally done in practice, or the way they are partitioned up by the standards committee or even what it takes to make a fast compiler (in either sense) are not automatically relevant.

Comment: Generally, most of the standard library content is for convenience, so you don't have to write more code.  Also, the content has been tested, so you don't need to waste time testing your own implementations.  For example, `std::list`.  In C language, you would either need an external library or write your own linked list.  The standard library contents allow your to have a shorter development cycle, in both typing and testing.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews OP is asking for something else, for those parts that you could not write yourself. In addition to what the question already mentions another example is [`std::offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) for which cppreference reports "offsetof cannot be implemented in standard C++ and requires compiler support"

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's true, but I'm not seeing the connection between that and my question. For example, that comment would not be relevant to a maintainer of a C++ compiler or standard library implementation and my question would be relevant to almost nobody other than such a person.

Comment: I've not seen a specific term that is applied to this.  I do know there are caveats in the standard that say the `<>` headers don't actually have to exist and that most of the stuff is exposition only, the standard just describes how it should behave

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `offsetof` is defined as a macro... but can't be evaluated until after the language parsing is running? Wow! I wonder what `#if offsetof(...) > 0 ...` is defined to do?

Comment: Some more examples: `std::is_final`/`std::is_trivially_copyable`/<a few more type traits>, `constexpr` support for `std::construct_at`/`std::destroy_at`/`std::bit_cast`/`std::addressof`, before C++23 `std::is_constant_evaluated`, `std::uncaught_exceptions`, maybe `std::rethrow_exception` (depending on your definition of "compiler support"). I've sometimes seen "pure library extension" used for when something can just be implemented as C++ code, but this phrase is not always used (and sometimes means "not-ABI-breaking library change" instead)

Comment: The standard library implementation and the compiler are developed in tandem, so the actual implementation is a detail that will vary by compiler.  I don't know if it's possible to answer your question in a generic way.

Comment: @MarkRansom That's true in practice (and a valid point in that context). I'm more interested in the theoretical context and question. "What _must_ be implemented in the compiler?" rather than "What _is_ implemented in the compiler?".

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai `offsetof` *can* be implemented in standard C++: https://godbolt.org/z/Ken7TK9Ma (though notably `std::addressof` needs compiler support)

Comment: @Artyer However that implementation only works in >=C++20 where as `offsetof` exists (and works) at least as far back as C++98 (and in version of _C_ to boot). Also, I'd not be at all surprised if that doesn't work in some obscure corner case.

Comment: @Artyer isn't your `my_offsetof()` implementation breaking the rules of `union` usage in C++? It initializes the `__array` member, but then reads from the `__obj` member, then accesses the `__array` member again. `union` in C++ doesn't allow type puning like that. Also, why use a loop instead of just checking if the address of `_MEMBER` falls between the address of `__obj[0]` and the address of `__obj[sizeof(__type)]`?

Comment: The standard does not consider the compiler and library to be separable, so it does not concern itself with questions like "How much of this could theoretically be made compiler-independent?"

Comment: In some cases even when no special compiler support is needed, implementations could still rely on it for better performance. For example, `libstdc++`:  `template<typename Tp, Tp Num> using make_integer_sequence = __make_integer_seq<integer_sequence, Tp, Num>;`.

Comment: @RaymondChen Also a valid point, ... to people on the standards committee. The question I'm asking is mostly of interest to maintainers of a stdlib or a compiler who want to spend as little time as possible wearing both hats. (Which I'll grant might by a purely theoretical group of people.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the standard doesn't attempt to list such things. Lacking such a thing, about all we could do would be to list as many such things as we know. SO's guidelines discourage questions asking for such lists though...

Comment: @JerryCoffin while I wouldn't object to things being listed (and I kind wish SO allowed that kind of question ... with proper labeling of them) I specifically asked the question the way I did to avoid that rule :0)

Answer (score 3):

The C++ spec doesn't really consider the library to be separate from the language, so any answer is going to be fairly wishy-washy. However, there is one quirk we can use to kinda-sorta have an answer...

https://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#compliance

> "16.4.2.5 Freestanding implementations"

> ... A freestanding implementation has an implementation-defined set of headers. This set shall include at least the headers shown in Table 27.

|  |  | **Subclause** | **Header** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | [[support.types]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.types) | Common definitions | <cstddef> |
|  | [[cstdlib.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdlib.syn) | C standard library | <cstdlib> |
|  | [[support.limits]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.limits) | Implementation properties | <cfloat>, <climits>, <limits>, <version> |
|  | [[cstdint.syn]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cstdint.syn) | Integer types | <cstdint> |
|  | [[support.dynamic]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.dynamic) | Dynamic memory management | <new> |
|  | [[support.rtti]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.rtti) | Type identification | <typeinfo> |
|  | [[support.srcloc]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.srcloc) | Source location | <source_location> |
|  | [[support.exception]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.exception) | Exception handling | <exception> |
|  | [[support.initlist]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.initlist) | Initializer lists | <initializer_list> |
|  | [[cmp]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmp) | Comparisons | <compare> |
|  | [[support.coroutine]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.coroutine) | Coroutines support | <coroutine> |
|  | [[support.runtime]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.runtime) | Other runtime support | <cstdarg> |
|  | [[concepts]](https://eel.is/c++draft/concepts) | Concepts library | <concepts> |
|  | [[errno]](https://eel.is/c++draft/errno) | Error numbers | <cerrno> |
|  | [[syserr]](https://eel.is/c++draft/syserr) | System error support | <system_error> |
|  | [[memory]](https://eel.is/c++draft/memory) | Memory | <memory> |
|  | [[type.traits]](https://eel.is/c++draft/type.traits) | Type traits | <type_traits> |
|  | [[ratio]](https://eel.is/c++draft/ratio) | Compile-time rational arithmetic | <ratio> |
|  | [[utility]](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility) | Utility components | <utility> |
|  | [[tuple]](https://eel.is/c++draft/tuple) | Tuples | <tuple> |
|  | [[optional]](https://eel.is/c++draft/optional) | Optional objects | <optional> |
|  | [[variant]](https://eel.is/c++draft/variant) | Variants | <variant> |
|  | [[expected]](https://eel.is/c++draft/expected) | Expected objects | <expected> |
|  | [[function.objects]](https://eel.is/c++draft/function.objects) | Function objects | <functional> |
|  | [[charconv]](https://eel.is/c++draft/charconv) | Primitive numeric conversions | <charconv> |
|  | [[bit]](https://eel.is/c++draft/bit) | Bit manipulation | <bit> |
|  | [[string.view]](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.view) | String view classes | <string_view> |
|  | [[string.classes]](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.classes) | String classes | <string> |
|  | [[c.strings]](https://eel.is/c++draft/c.strings) | Null-terminated sequence utilities | <cstring>, <cwchar> |
|  | [[array]](https://eel.is/c++draft/array) | Class template array | <array> |
|  | [[views.contiguous]](https://eel.is/c++draft/views.contiguous) | Contiguous access | <span> |
|  | [[views.multidim]](https://eel.is/c++draft/views.multidim) | Multidimensional access | <mdspan> |
|  | [[iterators]](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterators) | Iterators library | <iterator> |
|  | [[ranges]](https://eel.is/c++draft/ranges) | Ranges library | <ranges> |
|  | [[algorithms]](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms) | Algorithms library | <algorithm>, <numeric> |
|  | [[c.math]](https://eel.is/c++draft/c.math) | Mathematical functions for floating-point types | <cmath> |
|  | [[atomics]](https://eel.is/c++draft/atomics) | Atomics | <atomic> |
|  | [[debugging]](https://eel.is/c++draft/debugging) | Debugging | <debugging> |

As near as I can tell, this is a superset of the list of the parts of the standard library that require compiler support and cannot be written to be compiler-independent.  Nothing says that officially, but in practice, this list is the closest I've ever found to an objective answer.

In practice, a few of these can be written in portable C++, such as `std::string`.

Comment: A good starting point, I think your _~half_ is "somewhat pessimistic". I'm guessing it's closer to 95%, maybe north of 99% if you include stuff that can be done by calling out to CPU specific hand written (but still _compiler_ independent) ASM. (Ditto OS specific sys-calls.)

Comment: I was assuming target-independence as well.  Hand written ASM isn't portable. It's not even compiler-agnostic :/  MSVC and GCC use entirely different syntaxes for ASM.

Comment: If you go with a `.s` to `.o` assembler rather than inline ASM, that becomes less of an issue by extracting the compiler from the question. That's a reasonably well understood issue compared to the things that *must* be done by the compiler.

Comment: @BCS: That sure doesn't sound like portable C++ to me :)

Comment: Portability **between compilers** is the part in question. Between CPUs or OSs is a valid question, but not the question being asked here.

Comment: @BCS: (A) That's not C++ anymore, and (B) even ignoring that, you have to pick `.s` or `.o` because it's compiler-specific, and not portable between compilers.

Comment: Last I checked, 100% pure portable C++ can't even do I/O. All external interactions *inherently* reach out past the language abstractions. Portability isn't about eliminating that; it's about minimizing that. Having a small list of OS/Arch specific hooks is both necessarily and acceptable. --- And anything that can/must be done like that is specifically **not** what I'm asking about.

Comment: @BCS: 100% pure portable C++ can call `std::cout << 4;`, which is I/O. But you're right that chunks of the standard library themselves can't be written in 100% pure portable C++, such as the I/O component. That requires compiler compatibility.  In this case, probably via `[cstdlib.syn]`.

Comment: tl;dr; The types of comparability you are mentioning are the bits I'm _excluding_ from consideration in this question. --- `std::cout << 4;` could be written so that it bottoms out in terms of a forward declared function that is then provided to the linker by something other than the compiler. (`xxd -r impl.hex impl.o`?) If that function is `extern "C"`, then with a defined C-ABI, I don't think any comparability requirements left actually involve the **compiler.**

Comment: @BCS: There's one requirement on comparisons that could involve the compiler. When you have two unrelated pointers, `<` and `>` are not required to work on them--but `std::less` *is* required to work. On typical hardware, this is pretty trivial (just compare addresses), but a few machines have oddball addressing that requires the compiler to do a little extra work to create a total order on pointers so you get working comparison.